# Better way to load Mysql query in PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
$sql = <<<END
Select Sum(p)/Sum(w)*100 as present FROM attendance group by month
END;
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . ' - ' . mysql_error());
$names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $names[] = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions, are deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: @geomo I know that I shouldn't. As I understand mysql_function better, so I use it. However there might be time when I must move to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @MawiaHL: That time has come... that time was yesterday, to be honest. It's been three years(!) since `mysql_*` [was first put up for deprecation](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/66726), and not a moment too soon. Saying you're reluctant to change because the old extension feels familiar is understandable, but that attitude is like us still living in caves, because it felt familiar to our cave-men ancestors. Moving with the times is what gets you ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of how well you know the `mysql_*` functions, you shouldn't use them. There are counterparts within PDO. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860046#12860046) on stackoverflow for why.

This is how you'd do that in PDO:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=database", $user, $password);

// set the default for ->fetch() and ->fetchAll() to associative array
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// throw an exception instead of an error on fail
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


try {
    $sql = "(select sum(p) / sum(w) * 100) as present from attendance group by month";

    // make sure you have php5-mysqlnd installed.
    // (MySQL native driver. It makes upgrading PHP easy as there's no library conflicts).
    // You can also work with different versions of MySQL without errors.
    $names = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

    // array_column will take an associative array and a key and flatten it into an array
    return array_column($names, "present");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "<pre>" . $e->getTraceAsString() . "</pre>";
}
```

For error-handling, you should really use exceptions. Otherwise, check the value of `$db->errorInfo()`